# Include (google-service).json in (spring boot) .jar file

Tags: json, spring-boot, gradle, firebase-admin

We're trying to use firebase admin SDK, which uses a .json file (google-service.json) to access credentials, in a spring boot application. The problem however is that the json-file is not included in the jar when i build (We use gradle).

It runs fine from the IDE but when i try to run the .jar it complains about unfulfilled dependencies since it can't build the bean dependent on the non-existing .json.

I need a .jar because I want to deploy in a liberty websphere.

Is it even possible? If anyone else have some experience we would greatly appreciate some pointers.

Comment: what are the steps you have followed to build the jar ?

Comment: I had the .json at root level. Put it in resources folder and streamed it from there instead. Now everything works like a charm. Are there any potential pitfalls with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone (even though I doubt it) finds themselves in the same situation I've done the following to include the .json in the .jar:

Moved the .json to resources and

```
val classloader = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader
val serviceAccountJson = classloader.getResourceAsStream("google-services.json")
```

instead of using with the google-sevice.json at root level with

```
val serviceAccountJson = FileInputStream("google-services.json")
```

If anyone has a better solution I'd gladly implement that instead.